# Host Inspector message while installing CDH 4 - expected hostname and actual hostname

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am trying to install CDH 4 on Ubuntu 10.x. Everything worked fine. But the Host Inspector gave the following message.

host hadoop.ubuntu.com expected to have name hadoop.ubuntu.com, but resolved (InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()) to Ubuntu-64bit.

This is how the entry in the hosts file looks

192.168.56.101 hadoop.ubuntu.com Ubuntu-64-bit

So I have two queries
1. Is the syntax of specifying hostname in the line - 192.168.56.101 hadoop.ubuntu.com Ubuntu-64-bit, incorrect and what is the proper way?
2. If I let CDH 4 run with this message, will any functioning get affected?

Answer (score 0):

The cluster (single node though) started fine without any issues so far. So looks like this host inspector warning did not cause any problems. Also changing the syntax of the line of IP address in the hosts file causes more issues. So I am closing this question for now.